# How to cast obj in to string in typescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript, string, object

I used Angular 13 and fetch titles from JSON

```
this.variable = this.service('id', this.parentcontrol)
```

I got ID from JSON

then I send response to HTML page like this `{{variable.title}}`

either I used an accordion and I have this object for each row

```
{
question:'should be a string',
answer:'should be a string',
opened:false
}
```

my question is how can I send the string of this object

```
this.variable = this.service('id', this.parentcontrol)
```

to question?

I did like this in typescript

```
question : String(variable.title);
```

but I got null otherwise when I wrote like

```
question: 'hello world"
```

its works.

could you help me to fix this issue?

Comment: There are many layers of your question and a better reformulation will be good to explain what you are facing. Please do rework the copy of your post. But, already there are some stuff wrong in what you shared here. When you do `question: "Hello world"` you are not *assigning* value there, but you define a type for that property. Same when you do `question : String(variable.title);`.

Comment: This question is very confusing. `String(variable.title)` can't be used as a type, `const question: 'hello world"` is not valid because you're using a single quote and a double quote in combination, but would be a valid literal type otherwise. What IDE are you using? Is it not yelling at you for these bleeding issues?

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need to do type casting, rather something like this would do just fine.

```
const myObject = {
    title: 'foo',
};

const question: string = myObject.title;
const question2: typeof myObject['title'] = myObject.title;
```